# Dynamically populated scss values or how to change styles by user choice

Tags: css, sass

When building websites I use scss to write my stylesheet and gulp to put it together into style.css

I know there is a way to dynamically populate the values in css using style.php instead.Is there a way to dynamically populate my stylesheet with user choices (let's say user can chose background of the section, text color etc) and pass these values to my stylesheet to avoid make my php template files messy with inline styles (which for now is my solution to dynamically populate these values).

Thank you!

Comment: What is `style.php`? Inline styles are the only way to do this without dealing with writing files and solving caching/security issues. Have you considered CSS variables? That would let you avoid writing complex styling rules and have a single inline style block

Comment: Dear Tom, I came across `style.php` in this article: https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/ 
In my css I, of course, use CSS variables, but they are inside the .scss files. Do you suggest, rather than defining them in css, to define them in the head of the website inside `<style></style>` tags? That's a brilliant idea! I will try it right now! Thanks so much!